# Load report failed error and Session Expired issue on Crystal Report Viewer

Tags: crystal-reports

I added CrystalReportViewer control on my web page and found 2 main problems

Problem 1: Load report failed
It can't load crystal report and it shows the followin error:
The maximum report processing jobs limit configured by your system administrator has been reached

After I restart IIS, it can load the report again

Problem 2: Session expired
I added the control on a popup page. When I open and close the popup page several times, 
the session will expires suddenly. I am sure that this is not caused by session timeout.

Please advice

1. Which version of CrystalReportViewer is stable and bug free?
2. How to fix the above problems?

Development Environment:

- SAP Crystal Reports 2013 Support Pack 1
- Visual Studio Professional 2012
- .NET Framework 3.5
- Windows Server 2012
- Crystal Report Viewer control 
  (CrystalDecisions.Shared (v 13.0.8.1216), CrystalDecisions.Web (v 13.0.8.1216), CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine (v 13.0.8.1216))

Thanks,
Tony

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code :

```
Protected Sub Page_Unload(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Unload
    cryRpt.Close()
    cryRpt.Dispose()
End Sub
```